# Vocal epentética en el infinitivo del español colombiano

Tags: pronunciación, dialectos, colombia

Hoy un colombiano que conozco estaba leyendo una carta en voz alta.  Mantenía una pronunciación (o bien, característica lingüística) curiosa que no asociaba con su país natal, que es la existencia de una *-e* epentética en las formas del infinitivo.  En vez de *estamos aquí para celebrar*, dijo *estamos aquí para celebrare*, por ejemplo.  Ya que lo dijo con todos los infinitivos igual, estoy seguro de que no dijo algo como *estamos aquí para celebrar, eh...*

A pesar de que *celebrare* normalmente es una forma del futuro del subjuntivo, en algunos dialectos también es la forma infinitiva.  Lo curioso no es la existencia de esta forma, sino el hecho de que la escuché de alguien que (1) no autorreconocía la pronunciación, (2) no la tenía en el habla conversacional (solo al leer formalmente), (3) es de Colombia, que, que yo sepa, no la tiene, y (4) es un hombre muy culto.

Entonces, mi pregunta sería, imagino, si alguien sabría el posible origen de esta pronunciación... ¿es típico de alguna zona colombiana?  ¿de un registro oratorio?

Comment: De parte de (1) un Colombiano de nacimiento y (2) aunque no exageradamente pero si considerablemente culto :-) , te digo que no, esa pronunciación no es de ninguna region de Colombia que yo conozca. Tal vez el hombre es tan culto aprendió eso en alguna otra parte.

Comment: tal vez solo se le trabo la lengua, o simplemente la carta fue escrita por alguien de origen italiano (o no) y utilizo celebrare que en italiano significa celebrar. No es tan inusual entremezclar palabras de otros idiomas.

Comment: @rnrneverdies vi la carta, los infinitivos estaban escritos como normal (era una carta del arzobispo). Al principio pensaba que se le trabó la lengua pero ya que así pronunció todos los infinitivos, lo dudo

Comment: Esta forma de pronunciar los infinitivos constituye una afectación más o menos extendida. Hay un número de Les Luthiers en el que Marcos Mundstock la parodia; si lo encuentro, pondré un enlace aquí.

Comment: Me parece que es más preciso hablar de paragoge que de epéntesis.

Comment: Yo sugiero que esta pregunta se cierre. En Colombia no usamos esa pronunciación y el uso que de ella haga un individuo puntual no aporta al foro. En caso de que alguien de una repuesta esta sería basada en una opinión personal por lo que estaría "off-topic". Que opinas guifa?

Comment: @DGaleano, concuerdo con usted, o que al menos no se use la etiqueta `Colombia` para esta pregunta.

Comment: En Colombia no usamos esa pronunciación y el uso que de ella haga un individuo puntual no aporta al foro

Comment: ¿Tal vez será por influencia del italiano o el latín?

Comment: En el sur de Chile es habitual en personas mayores decir _el sure, la verdade, voy a venire, voy a comprare_, etc., y sobre todo _la calore_. ¿No será chileno el amigo?

Comment: Eso no se usa en ninguna de las regiones de Colombia, seguro que la persona es de Colombia?

Answer (score 9):

A falta de una respuesta más académica, recojo aquí lo más relevante de lo que se ha dicho en los comentarios, más alguna cosa que he investigado en el intertanto. Si se juzga oportuno, lo podemos convertir en *wiki* para que aporte más gente.

La **epéntesis** se refiere a la aparición de un sonido (previamente inexistente) en una palabra. El [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FvD3RnC) cita como ejemplo el caso de *tenré*>*tendré* (sugiriendo que la primera es una forma arcaica de la segunda, que adquirió la *d* por epéntesis y luego se volvió convencional.

La **paragoge** se refiere a la aparición de un sonido *al final de una palabra*. Según quién la defina, es excluyente con o un caso particular de la epéntesis. En cualquier caso, pareciera que el fenómeno señalado en la pregunta debe ser más propiamente llamado por este segundo nombre (gracias @Rodrigo).

La *e paragógica* (al final de verbos en infinitivo y otras palabras terminadas en consonante) es un fenómeno de aparición frecuente en la historia en el castellano.

Según [este artículo](http://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/fichero_articulo?codigo=298580&orden=57626), la -e final se perdió en nuestra lengua como parte de un proceso que tiene su cúlmine en el siglo XI. Sin embargo reapareció en la poesía como un recurso para resguardar la rima y el número de sílabas de los versos y se mantuvo por algunos siglos más (al parecer, cuando en el Quijote se usa el adjetivo *felice* es en forma de arcaísmo). Los filólogos castellanos se refieren a ese recurso también como *e paragógica*.

Por lo que señalan algunos colombianos en los comentarios de esta misma pregunta, el uso de la *e paragógica* no sería parte de ninguno de los acentos propios en ese país. Sin embargo, sí hay testimonios de su existencia en el mundo hispanohablante actual. Algunos ejemplos:

- En Nuevo México se ha [documentado](https://books.google.cl/books?id=r8u8wqCXKA8C&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=e+paragogica+nuevo+mexico&source=bl&ots=thCuyJRF91&sig=tZxqnwJeFQQgE_I6xUgNXf2tMLo&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) la aparición de una *e paragógica* entre hablantes nativos de castellano.
- En zonas rurales del centro y -especialmente- sur de Chile constituye un fenómeno tan arraigado, que en el habla coloquial urbana se ha asentado el término [*sure*](https://www.google.com/search?q="me+voy+al+sure") para significar específicamente la zona sur de ese país.
- En los verbos con imperativo irregular monosilábico, suele ocurrir la forma bisilábica "regular" ([*sale*](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/sal-sale.1651519/) y *pone* en vez de *sal* y *pon*, con *e paragógica*) en el habla inculta de algunos lugares (p. ej., Las Canarias y Chile), probablemente como arcaísmo.
- A un nivel al parecer bastante transversal entre países de habla hispana (a juzgar, entre otras cosas, por la proporción de votos del comentario de @Gorpik), aparece la *e paragógica* como forma de habla afectada o como vicio inadvertido y ocasional en el habla de una persona que normalmente no la usa. Recuerdo el caso de un político chileno, que sin ser del sur (y con un acento razonablemente clasificable como *chileno informal culto*), alterna entre [caer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlFtO9yduy0) y [no caer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NeZWaHM3Y8s).

A falta de más antecedentes, y dado que se trata de 1) una persona que normalmente no agrega las *e finales*, 2) ni tiene un entorno lingüístico que pueda haberle influido, y visto que 3) los verbos estaban escritos correctamente en la carta, lo más plausible parece ser que se trataba de un caso del último tipo (afectación o vicio no atribuible al acento).

Comment: ¡Fantástica labor de recopilación, ordenamiento y análisis! El parágrafo que empieza con _la e paragógica_ y el siguiente podrían fusionarse, pero no acabo de ver por dónde hincarle el diente. Después, no acabo de entender en el penúltimo párrafo cuando comentas lo de _alterna [enlace] entre caer y no caer [enlace] es esto_.

Comment: @fedorqui, la verdad es que eran dos ejemplos de videos en que pasan ambas cosas. Cuando traté de ponerlos como dos links en un paréntesis separados por comas, tuve problemas. Primero busqué uno en que pasara mucho y otro en que no pasara, pero no lo logré. Parece que el personaje ha mejorado este vicio con el tiempo, pero no ha sido ni negro antes ni blanco ahora.